# How to fix ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Am getting error as `ORA-01821: date format not recognized` for below query. I tried with `to_date` function also. But it wont work.

Query

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp('27-08-2021 06:24:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SI'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SI') 
FROM LOG_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem really borders on being a typo, but the format mask for seconds is `SS`, not `SI`.  Use this version:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('27-08-2021 06:24:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
            'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM LOG_TABLE;
```

Presumably the input to `TO_TIMESTAMP` is really intended to be a column from the log table.  As a side note, you should avoid storing dates and timestamps as text.